# GCC "__gmpn_invert_limb" compilation error

Tags: gcc, linker, compiler

I'm currently trying to compile GCC 4.9.2 using GCC 4.2.
The problem I have run into is that I have a working GMP installation (6.0.0a) but GCC fails to link to it after a while. The error I get is:

```
Undefined reference to __gmpn_invert_limb
```

and then it shows some methods that use that function, although make check (on gmp) determined that this function is working fine.

Commands used:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/gcc --with-gmp=/prefix/path/of/gmp/configure
make
```

Any ideas?

PS: I also tried downloading the gmp source and putting it in gcc/gmp like I did with mpfr. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

Typically in gmp's configure file if an os isn't provided it uses none by default, this, at least for ARM, caused the host_os and target_os alias' to be incorrect and led to the undefined references you refer to.

The way I fixed this for arm-linux-androideabi was changing both instances of

```
 - linux*android*)

 + linux-android*)
```

in gmp/configure.  I'm not sure what your os or cpu is, but defining them in your configure command might help.